# Как отобразить html текст не как текст, а как готовый html

Tags: html

Добрый день.

Есть текст `<span ....>text</span> <img ...>  <p>text</p>`.

Как его отобразить в обработанном виде, без тегов?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну как процесс?

Answer (score 1):

Создать файл *.html и отрыть его в браузере и увидишь преобразованный текст HTML.

**UPDATE**

Открой messenger.php и убери оттуда htmlspecialchars. Так как он обрабатывает ajax-запрос и возвращает уже текст с заменой спецсимволов

Comment: В чате значит нету преобразователя html кода. Если к чату Вы имеете полный доступ(доступ к коду), то этот момент легко исправить. А вот если это внешний сервис, который Вы подключили у себя на сайте - то тут ничего не получиться сделать.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин костыли пишите. Используйте BB коды.

Comment: я имею полный доступ. В базе хранится тегами, а потом надо не теги показывать, а соответствующее отображение.

Comment: Дать ссылку на ресурс(чат) можешь?

Comment: http://ai1.dev.p-24.ru/   в сообщениях  логин pao@p-24.ru пароль 112233

Comment: Вот, теперь всё стало ясно! У тебя срабатывает метод замены спецсимволов, т.е. у тебя идет замена:

< на &lt;
> на &gt;
" на &quot;
& на &amp; 
и т.д.

Comment: http://ai1.dev.p-24.ru/im/?peer=p1554   надо отобразить, например, ТЕКСТ

     <span style="font-weight: bold;">ЖИРНЫЙ <span style="text-decoration: underline;">ЖИРН ПОДЧЁРКН</span>&nbsp;<img src="http://ai1.dev.p-24.ru/js/chat/icons/smiley-red.png" alt="red" /></span>

Comment: Там часть на php и часть на jquery во время чата, когда добавляешь новое сообщение

Comment: Да, у тебя при помощи jquery отправляется введенный текст на сервер, путем ajax-запроса. Текст обрабатывается файлом  messenger.php и он потом возвращает отформатированный текст, в котором была произведена замена спец. символов. Открой этот файл и найди строку содержащую htmlspecialchars. 
Затем удали эту функцию и все будет работать! Получилось?